# Will git pull include new submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-pull

When I clone a repository with the following command, it automatically includes submodules.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/xxxxxxxx
```

I have a question. If you later update the repository with `git pull`, will it include the newly added submodules? (if there is a newly added submodule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any new submodule added, you may have to use

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Post that, the following should be suffice

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

Comment: `git pull --recurse-submodules` Does this command only update submodules, or will it update the parent repository together?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules You can read this for info